# Sitecore multi-site preview mode not setting sc_mode cookie

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

We have a multi-site solution with each site representing a different country.

Publish preview works correctly for the page that is chosen for the preview however, on our live environment only, as soon as any site links are clicked in the preview, the pages will not be found (they are not yet published).

We have determined that this is because no sc_mode cookie with a value of preview is set for the site that is being previewed.

On our development environments, as soon as the initial preview page is loaded sc_mode cookies are created for each of the sites, e.g. australia#sc_mode, uk#sc_mode, france#sc_mode, etc.

On our live environment the creation of these site based cookies never occurs.

Can anyone suggest what configuration differences between the environments might create this situation?

Comment: Do the following settings appear in the web.config; httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="true" they have caused issues with Sitecore setting cookies in the past

Comment: What about adding `?sc_mode=preview` to the query string?

Comment: I had considered that Mark however, it seems like a hacky solution as it seems to me there must be a reason why cookies are created on some environments and not others

Comment: I have seen issues with rewrites causing site resolving to not work correctly and if the site can't be resolved it can default to website or shell which may have preview disabled. maybe add some code in to display what site sitecore thinks you are in